# Why doesn't the "whatis" command work?

Tags: configuration, path, man

When I run the `whatis` command, it just outputs "nothing appropriate." no matter what command I pass to it.

```
$ whatis grep
grep: nothing appropriate.
```

The output of `whatis -d grep`:

```
From the config file /etc/manpath.config:
  Mandatory mandir `/usr/man'.
  Mandatory mandir `/usr/share/man'.
  Mandatory mandir `/usr/local/share/man'.
  Path `/bin' mapped to mandir `/usr/share/man'.
  Path `/usr/bin' mapped to mandir `/usr/share/man'.
  Path `/sbin' mapped to mandir `/usr/share/man'.
  Path `/usr/sbin' mapped to mandir `/usr/share/man'.
  Path `/usr/local/bin' mapped to mandir `/usr/local/man'.
  Path `/usr/local/bin' mapped to mandir `/usr/local/share/man'.
  Path `/usr/local/sbin' mapped to mandir `/usr/local/man'.
  Path `/usr/local/sbin' mapped to mandir `/usr/local/share/man'.
  Path `/usr/X11R6/bin' mapped to mandir `/usr/X11R6/man'.
  Path `/usr/bin/X11' mapped to mandir `/usr/X11R6/man'.
  Path `/usr/games' mapped to mandir `/usr/share/man'.
  Path `/opt/bin' mapped to mandir `/opt/man'.
  Path `/opt/sbin' mapped to mandir `/opt/man'.
  Global mandir `/usr/man', catdir `/var/cache/man/fsstnd'.
  Global mandir `/usr/share/man', catdir `/var/cache/man'.
  Global mandir `/usr/local/man', catdir `/var/cache/man/oldlocal'.
  Global mandir `/usr/local/share/man', catdir `/var/cache/man/local'.
  Global mandir `/usr/X11R6/man', catdir `/var/cache/man/X11R6'.
  Global mandir `/opt/man', catdir `/var/cache/man/opt'.
  Global mandir `/snap/man', catdir `/var/cache/man/snap'.
  Added sections: `1', `n', `l', `8', `3', `2', `3posix', `3pm', `3perl', `3am', `5', `4', `9', `6', `7'.
path directory /usr/local/sbin is in the config file
  adding /usr/local/man to manpath
  adding /usr/local/share/man to manpath
path directory /usr/local/bin is in the config file
path directory /usr/sbin is in the config file
  adding /usr/share/man to manpath
path directory /usr/bin is in the config file
path directory /sbin is in the config file
path directory /bin is in the config file
path directory /usr/games is in the config file
path directory /usr/local/games is not in the config file
adding mandatory man directories
warning: /usr/man: No such file or directory
add_nls_manpaths(): processing /usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
checking for locale en_US.UTF-8
adding /usr/local/man to manpathlist
adding /usr/share/man to manpathlist
final search path = /usr/local/man:/usr/share/man
path=/usr/local/man
warning: can't read the fallback whatis text database /usr/local/man/whatis
path=/usr/share/man
warning: can't read the fallback whatis text database /usr/share/man/whatis
grep: nothing appropriate.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The messages say you have no manpages.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I have the man pages installed and they work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

The messages tell you the problem:

```
final search path = /usr/local/man:/usr/share/man
path=/usr/local/man
warning: can't read the fallback whatis text database /usr/local/man/whatis
path=/usr/share/man
warning: can't read the fallback whatis text database /usr/share/man/whatis
grep: nothing appropriate.
```

and (depending on the system used, there are different manpages to read), but [for example](https://final%20search%20path%20=%20/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man%20path=/usr/local/man%20warning:%20can%27t%20read%20the%20fallback%20whatis%20text%20database%20/usr/local/man/whatis%20path=/usr/share/man%20warning:%20can%27t%20read%20the%20fallback%20whatis%20text%20database%20/usr/share/man/whatis%20grep:%20nothing%20appropriate.):

> ***index***  databases  are  used  during  the  search,  and  are  updated by the mandb program.
> Depending on your installation, this may be run by a periodic cron job, or may need to  be
> run  manually  after  new  manual pages have been installed.  To produce an old style text
> whatis database from the relative index database, issue the command:
>
> `whatis -M manpath -w '*' | sort > manpath/whatis`
>
> where ***`manpath`*** is a manual page hierarchy such as `/usr/man`.

Likely, the "`whatis`" files are missing or corrupt in `/usr/local/man` and `/usr/share/man`.  Recreating those would improve matters.

Comment: Is it better to use `whatis -M manpath...` or just use `mandb` as stated in `whatis` man page? or will both do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `mandb`, which should create this stuff automatically. If you installed man pages manually, and mandb isn't installed, then install mandb first.